# Visual studio code Espressif IDF IRAM_ATTR

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32, esp-idf

I have installed Espressif IDF(1.5.0) in Visual studio code.

When i run this code in the Espressif IDE i have no problems but when i use Visual studio code i get an error on IRAM_ATTR saying "expected a type specifier", and a second error in the same line "expected a {".
I get also an error on portTICK_PERIOD_MS saying "identifier portTICK_PERIOD_MS is undefined"

What can be wrong ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "driver/uart.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "esp_intr_alloc.h"
#include "soc/uart_reg.h"
#include "soc/uart_struct.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"



#define TXD_PIN                         (GPIO_NUM_17)
#define RXD_PIN                         (GPIO_NUM_16)
#define UART                            UART_NUM_2
#define BUF_SIZE                        (1024)
#define RD_BUF_SIZE                     (BUF_SIZE)

static intr_handle_t                    handle_console;

static const char *TAG = "uart_events";
char rxbuf[256];

static void IRAM_ATTR uart_intr_handler(void *arg)
{
    uint16_t rx_fifo_len, i=0;

    ESP_EARLY_LOGI(TAG,"%s", "Interrupt entered...");

   
}


void app_main(void)
{

        esp_log_level_set(TAG, ESP_LOG_INFO);
        

        /* Configure parameters of an UART driver,
        * communication pins and install the driver */
        uart_config_t uart_config = {
            .baud_rate = 115200,
            .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
            .parity = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
            .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
            .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE,
            .source_clk = UART_SCLK_APB,
        };

        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_param_config(UART, &uart_config));

        //Set UART log level
        esp_log_level_set(TAG, ESP_LOG_INFO);

        //Set UART pins (using UART0 default pins ie no changes.)
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_set_pin(UART, TXD_PIN, RXD_PIN, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE));

        //Install UART driver, and get the queue.
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_driver_install(UART, BUF_SIZE * 2, 0, 0, NULL, 0));

        // release the pre registered UART handler/subroutine
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_isr_free(UART));

        // register new UART subroutine
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_isr_register(UART,uart_intr_handler, NULL, ESP_INTR_FLAG_IRAM, &handle_console));

        // enable RX interrupt
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_enable_rx_intr(UART));

        

        while(1)
        {
              vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Softtoon - please edit your question to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem. In this case it should be simple to just define a function with `IRAM_ATTR`. It's helpful to see an entire program that has demonstrates the problem. In this case, we have no idea what header files you're including or what other code may have influenced your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Include-file references are missing. In your .vscode folder look for `c_cpp_properties.json`. If not found, create one.

Update properties like include path as per this:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code 1.70.3, Windows SP1 7x64, esp-idf-v4.4.6, VSCode ESP-IDF extension v1.6.5, C/C++ IntelliSense v1.19.9

The project will have .vscode, it contains *.json files that need to be changed.

---

**Problem 1:** IntelliSense is present, but the environment may not give any indication if there is a problem.

***Solution:*** file `settings.json`

change
`"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser"` to `"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "default"`.

It is better to erase the value inside the quotes then press Ctrl + space and select "default".
Save and close. The studio will offer to restart the environment, agree.

Now if there is an error in the main.c file, a red wavy line appears beneath that code.
[Found here](https://esp32tutorials.com/install-esp32-esp-idf-windows-integrate-vs-code/).

---

**Problem 2:** Visual Studio does not see constants from `sdkconfig`

***Solution:*** file `c_cpp_properties.json`

To the "include Path" and "browse" section add

```
"${workspaceFolder}/build/config"
```

the full config will be below

---

**Problem 3:** Visual Studio does not see the `portTICK_PERIOD_MS` constant. (portTICK_PERIOD_MS is undefined)

***Solution:*** file `c_cpp_properties.json`

Before changing, make a build of the project, because the file "c_cpp_properties.json" will appear in the build folder

After "name": "ESP-IDF", add the lines:

```
"cStandard": "c17",
"cppStandard": "c++17",
"compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json",
```

[read more here](https://github.com/espressif/vscode-esp-idf-extension/issues/1073#issuecomment-1804896911) and [here](https://github.com/espressif/vscode-esp-idf-extension/blob/master/docs/C_CPP_CONFIGURATION.md#configuration-with-compile_commandsjson)

---

`c_cpp_properties.json` before changes:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "ESP-IDF",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Espressif\\tools\\xtensa-esp32-elf\\esp-2021r2-patch3-8.4.0\\xtensa-esp32-elf\\bin\\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe",
            "includePath": [
                "${config:idf.espIdfPath}/components/**",
                "${config:idf.espIdfPathWin}/components/**",
                "${config:idf.espAdfPath}/components/**",
                "${config:idf.espAdfPathWin}/components/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${config:idf.espIdfPath}/components",
                    "${config:idf.espIdfPathWin}/components",
                    "${config:idf.espAdfPath}/components/**",
                    "${config:idf.espAdfPathWin}/components/**",
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": false
            },
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

`c_cpp_properties.json` after changes:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "ESP-IDF",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Espressif\\tools\\xtensa-esp32-elf\\esp-2021r2-patch3-8.4.0\\xtensa-esp32-elf\\bin\\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe",
            "includePath": [
                "${config:idf.espIdfPath}/components/**",
                "${config:idf.espIdfPathWin}/components/**",
                "${config:idf.espAdfPath}/components/**",
                "${config:idf.espAdfPathWin}/components/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/build/config"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${config:idf.espIdfPath}/components",
                    "${config:idf.espIdfPathWin}/components",
                    "${config:idf.espAdfPath}/components/**",
                    "${config:idf.espAdfPathWin}/components/**",
                    "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "${workspaceFolder}/build/config"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": false
            },
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```